# Translate an SQL subquery to a more efficient version

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I'm working with a moderately large MSAccess .mdb file that I need to manipulate with SQL. Unfortunately some statements which work in theory seem to cause it to hang, and I've run into a brick wall.

[Here is a simplified representation in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/080a5/6)

Three tables: products, product_category, and categories
I need to SELECT categories that ONLY contain items that have the field 'HIDE = 1'
If a category contains products that are hide = 0, it should not be selected.

I can do this relatively easily with subqueries, but the query stalls out. In the past queries that rely on left joins seem to execute efficiently, but I cannot wrap my mind around joins enough to translate this query into that format.

EDIT:

```
SELECT c.categoryid 
FROM product_category AS c
      LEFT JOIN
      (
          SELECT DISTINCT c.categoryid 
          FROM  product_category AS c
                LEFT JOIN products AS p 
                  ON c.catalogid = p.catalogid
          WHERE p.hide = 0
      )    y ON y.categoryid = c.categoryid

WHERE y.categoryid IS NULL
```

Someone posted the above query as an answer but then for some reason deleted it. As far as I can tell it works and works quickly. I consider this question to be answered. If I remember I will self-post the answer once the timer allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to un-correlate the subquery eg...

```
SELECT c.categoryid FROM product_category AS c
WHERE c.categoryid NOT IN 

(SELECT DISTINCT c1.categoryid FROM product_category AS c1
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON c1.catalogid = p.catalogid
WHERE p.hide = 0)
```

Note how I have aliased the subquery `product_category` table as `c1` instead of `c` - This means the subquery will only execute once as opposed to once for every row of the your main query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/080a5/8/0)

Note that there will no doubt be *more* efficiencies still to be found however I think this will suffice for your purposes.

In fact there is no need for a LEFT JOIN here I don't think ie...

```
SELECT c.categoryid FROM product_category AS c
WHERE c.categoryid NOT IN 

(SELECT DISTINCT c1.categoryid FROM product_category AS c1
INNER JOIN products AS p ON c1.catalogid = p.catalogid
WHERE p.hide = 0)
```

..This will afford you some extra speed.

Comment: Oh I wish that that would have solved it. Still stalls out. Someone else had posted a query that seems to be a winner, but then deleted it as an answer. I posted it as an edit to the original question.

Comment: Oh dear I'm sorry. I noticed there were a number of deleted answers. How many rows are we talking about in these tables?

Comment: And at what stage did speed become an issue?

Comment: For day-to-day use speed isn't an issue, it is for special custom projects like this where I run into problems. The product_category table has probably 150,000 rows

Comment: Changing the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN didn't make any noticeable difference. How do I view deleted answers? The one I posted in the edit seems perfect

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure on viewing deleted answers, I think they have gone. It's interesting why the `LEFT JOIN` solution is quicker than the `NOT IN` solution. This is not *usually* the case... Perhaps post that as another question and hopefully the rightful correct-answer-owner may turn up :)

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one categoryid per catalogid then you can get rid of the distinct:

```
Select
  c.id, c.categoryname
From
  category c
Where
  Not Exists (
    Select 
      'x'
    From 
      products p
        Inner Join
      product_category pc
        on pc.catalogid = p.catalogid
    Where
      pc.categoryid = c.id and
      p.hide = 0
  )
```

Edited - the test data in the fiddle seems wrong, I've corrected it. This should work now

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56f5e/1/0

Comment: removing the product_category from the Exists query should benefit performance by not hitting this table twice.